# Programmatically listing Bigquery datasets to which access has been granted, without knowing project ID in advance

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way (using the BigQuery API) to programmatically list **all datasets** to which an account has been granted access, **without** knowing the name of the project(s) containing these datasets ahead of time? I have a feeling that the API may not expose this information.

I am looking to obtain something similar to the list of datasets which appears on the left hand side of the BigQuery web console.

I am referring to datasets where I **do not** have access to the project which contains them, and have been granted access to a specific dataset only. Otherwise, we could simply use the API to list projects and then query the list of datasets for each project.

Presumably this would have to exclude public datasets (too numerous), and include only those to which my account has been explicitly been granted access.

Comment: (btw, took a second to edit out the thanks in your post. While it's definitely a nice thought to put it in, it's considered noise on Stack :) you show respect and appreciation by posting quality posts and voting according to quality :). Welcome to the site!)

Comment: Have you tried something on your own?

Comment: I have tried exploring the API, but I cannot find anything which looks like it will work.
 
projects().list() only returns projects for which you have project-level access. And datasets().list() requires projectId as a parameter.

Comment: If you already know the name of a project containing a dataset to which you have access, then you can list the datasets to which you have access using datasets().list(projectId) (even if you don't have project-level access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this in the BigQuery API. As you say, you can get a list of projects that you're a member of, and then list the datasets in those projects, but there's no way to get a complete list of all datasets that have been shared with you.

We'd like to offer better search and discovery features in the future, but unfortunately it's not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Google has API explorers for most its tools. Whenever you have such a question, I would suggest looking up the explorer, as it gives you exactly what's mandatory, what you can and cannot do.

If you look up the API explorer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/list) (from "dataset -> list" in the official doc), you see there is only ONE mandatory field : projectID. So the answer to your question is no, you DO need the name of the project

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the API explorer, which is why I am asking this question. There is also project->list, but this only returns projects for which you have project-level access (and not projects for which you have only been granted access to some dataset).

Maybe I should have noted this in my original question, but I was attempting to distil it down and avoid adding any fluff

Comment: @JasonDavey including what you've tried and more details isn't fluff :). Anyway, yeah without the CLI (and I think the CLI has the same problem as "projects->list"), I don't see a way to do it straight :S

Comment: Yeah - it seems like it may not be possible. This may be because this would in theory return a list of every public dataset in the world, so there would be too many results. What I would really like is a way to list only those to which I have been explicitly granted access.

Comment: @JasonDavey bingo. I don't know exactly how many public datasets there are, but it would definitely grab them. You're looking for "any dataset I can query" and ALL the public ones follow that criteria. Not sure there's a solution here

Comment: Agreed. Maybe I can petition Google to implement an "all datasets I can query, excluding those which are public" =P. I think for now the only "workaround" is to manually create a list of such projects and store it in config somewhere

Comment: @JasonDavey The best place to do so would be on one of our issue trackers. I assume the bigquery one would be utmost appropriate. Here's the link : https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

Using [BQ command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#listdatasets):

```
bq ls --format=prettyjson
```

this returns a JSON formatted like:

```
[
    {
        "datasetId": "wr_1"
    },
    {
        "datasetId": "wr_2"
    },
    {
        "datasetId": "wr_3"
    },
    {
        "datasetId": "wr_4"
    }
]
```

You can do this also via API but you need to do multiple calls

- first obtain the projects:
  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/projects/list
- then obtain the datasets from the project https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/list

Comment: I was about to comment about the lack of a way to do this with the API. crafty edit sir! :P Without a double API call, I don't see another way to get that indeed (besides the CLI, but if the need is API based... might not be workable for OP)

Comment: As far as I can tell, projects->list only returns projects for which you have been granted project-level access. I am trying to get a list of individual datasets to which access has been granted (but for which I have no project-level access).